# Can not select Development Team in xcode, just show Personal Team

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, apple-developer-account

my Apple ID just join a development Team

But when I login that account to xcode

It just show personal Team (image below)

so I can not archive app and distribute to testflight

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be added there automatically. Make sure you set the right email on your portal.